# merge two javascript object having a common array but contains different value

Tags: javascript, object

```
var state1 = {
"up":{"name":"Uttar Pradesh","district":{"saharanpur":{"name":"Saharanpur","tehsil":{"behat":{"name":"Behat","village":["Alliwala"]}}}}}
};

var state2 = {
"up":{"name":"Uttar Pradesh","district":{"saharanpur":{"name":"Saharanpur","tehsil":{"behat":{"name":"Behat","village":["sachin"]}}}}}
};
```

result must be:

```
result = {
"up":{"name":"Uttar Pradesh","district":{"saharanpur":{"name":"Saharanpur","tehsil":{"behat":{"name":"Behat","village":["Alliwala","sachin"]}}}}}
};
```

in the scenario i don't know the content of the state1 object and if the object1 having key same like object2 present then it should push only the array value of state2 into state1 array

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I know the answer will involve using `JSON.parse()` and then the real question is how to merge the 2 objects and finally using `JSON.stringify()` to present your result.

Comment: What did you try? All you need to know is how to write a loop and access an object variable.

Comment: actually i need to merge two objects

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: var state2 = {
"up":{"name":"Uttar Pradesh","district":{"saharanpur":{"name":"Saharanpur","tehsil":{"behat":{"name":"Behat","village":["Alliwala"]}}}}}
};

var state1 = {
"up":{"name":"Uttar Pradesh","district":{"saharanpur":{"name":"Saharanpur","tehsil":{"behat":{"name":"Behat","village":["sachin"]}}}}}
}

result must be

result = {
"up":{"name":"Uttar Pradesh","district":{"saharanpur":{"name":"Saharanpur","tehsil":{"behat":{"name":"Behat","village":["sachin"]}}},"alhabad":{"name":"Alhabad","tehsil":{"rampur":{"name":"Rampur","village":["firozpur"]}}}}}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a new object and append arrays with the items from the already inserted array.

```js
function deepMerge(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        if (Array.isArray(source[k])) {
            if (!Array.isArray(target[k])) {
                target[k] = [];
            }          
            target[k] = target[k].concat(source[k]);
            return;
        }
        if (source[k] && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
            target[k] = target[k] || {};
            deepMerge(source[k], target[k]);
            return;
        }
        target[k] = source[k];
    });
}

var state1 = { up: { name: "Uttar Pradesh", district: { saharanpur: { name: "Saharanpur", tehsil: { behat: { name: "Behat", village: ["Alliwala"] } } } } } },
    state2 = { up: { name: "Uttar Pradesh", district: { saharanpur: { name: "Saharanpur", tehsil: { behat: { name: "Behat", village: ["sachin"] } } } } } },
    result = {};

deepMerge(state1, result);
deepMerge(state2, result);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
var finalState = combineArrays(state2,state1);


function combineArrays(array1,array2){
    var finalArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = array1.length; i < len; i++) {
      finalArray.push([array1[i][0], array2[i][0]]);
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: state2 and state1 are not array they are object so we can't use array.length in this 

and moreover it gives us wrong result